# Binary Search Tree Insert Method using Recursion is not Working (Python)

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I typically lean towards iterative solutions for my code but I have recently been struggling with recursion and backtracking for upcoming interviews. So, I was practicing implementing a Binary Search Tree from scratch using Recursion.

What is the issue with the node.data not being recognized? Plus does anyone have any advice with Recursion/Backtracking Algorithms for good practice? I have been spending a lot of time in the debugger stepping through my function but I am still a little iffy on how the stack call when you step backwards works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!

**Error:**
"
if data < node.data:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'"

```
class Node2():
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data


class BFS_Recursive():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.numNodes = None

    def insert(self, val):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = Node2(val)
        else:
            self._insert(self.root, val)

    def _insert(self, node, data):  # I cant figure out why this does not work
        if data < node.data:
            if node.left == None:
                node.left = Node2(data)
            node.left = self._insert(node.left, data)
        elif data > node.data:
            if node.right == None:
                node.right = Node2(data)
            node.right = self._insert(node.left, data)

    def search(self, root, key):
        if root:
            if root.data == key:
                return True
            elif key < root.data:
                return self.search(root.left, key)
            elif key > root.data:
                return self.serach(root.right, key)
        return False


r_bst = BFS_Recursive()
r_bst.insert(5)
r_bst.insert(1)
r_bst.insert(3)
r_bst.insert(7)
r_bst.insert(9)
```

Comment: You do this on both left and right: `self._insert(node.left, data)`. The second one should be `node.right = self._insert(node.right, data)`

Comment: You are a legend! I've spent over 1.5 hours on this simple issue ugh.. Thank you so much, it works..